# Excel Query From Web - Old laptop OK, new PC not OK

Tags: excel, powerquery

I bought a new desktop due to the need of faster machine. However, when I tried to work on excel to get data from a website, table is not showing in the new PC. In the query Navigator, it only shows Document (Kind, Name, Children, Text). This is kind a unusual for me because i didn't face this problem in my old laptop. Normally it shows document and other table/s (0,1,2,...). Attached images for further details

[image: Old PC]
[image: New PC]

I tried to dig on data source setting but didn't succeed. I tried to look on Query options and Access Web Content, to make sure old laptop settings and new desktop are same, but still fail to show the other tables. Also tried to uninstall/reinstall office 365 but didn't work as well.

I attached Excel query Navigator screenshot from old laptop and New PC for better understanding of the the problem. For sure I missed some setting but struggling where to dig further. Both machine installed with MS office 365, expecting same scraping capability fore both old and new.

Comment: Don't know if your privacy settings are even remotely associated with your problem - but they might be - so I suggest using your old laptop and reviewing the privacy settings for that query and making sure your new desktop complies with them.  Or you could try completely removing them to rule out the possibility.  Also, I don't know why your question was down voted, it may not necessarily be reproducable or have any code but it seems like a good relevant question that may have an answer that helps others.

Comment: I did check both privacy levels, and credentials as well of both PCs. They are the same, but still, new PC unable to get the tables. If I remember it correctly, I was able to put my credentials (username/password, as prompted by excel) but now, even I put the same credential, excel error notification credentials are "invalid". Im pretty sure the credentials that I entered are correct as I was able to access the actual website directly.

Comment: Have you confirmed but queries are identical in the advanced query editor?

Comment: Queries are the same. Actually is the same exact file opened in different PCs.